# Extracting a Certain portion of a String (Substring) in C

Tags: c, substring, extract, c-strings, function-definition

I am trying to extract the name of a store from strings that are stored as char arrays using the language C. Each one contains the price of an item and the store it is located at. I have many strings that follow this format, but I have provided I few examples below:

```
199 at Amazon
139 at L.L.Bean
379.99 at Best Buy
345 at Nordstrom
```

How could I extract the name of the store from these strings?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Find the `"at "` position using `strstr`, then take the rest.

Comment: Other ways: Use [strtok](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) or [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Comment: @Stormcaller25 What do you mean by the term "extract"? do you need to create a character array that will  contain  the name or you need to get a pointer that points to the name?

Comment: `strcpy(yourbuff, strstr(str,"at") + 3);` assuming the that `str` contains `"at"`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I meant create a character array that will contain the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char *sought = "at ";
char *pos = strstr(str, sought);
if(pos != NULL)
{
    pos += strlen(sought);
    // pos now points to the part of the string after "at";
}
else
{
    // sought was not find in str
}
```

If you want to extract a portion after `pos`, but not the entire remaining string, you can use `memcpy`:

```
const char *sought = "o "; 
char *str = "You have the right to remain silent";
char *pos = strstr(str, sought);

if(pos != NULL)
{
    char word[7];

    pos += strlen(sought); 
    memcpy(word, pos, 6);
    word[6] = '\0';
    // word now contains "remain\0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was already pointed in comments you can use standard function `strstr`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * extract_name( const char *record, const char *prefix )
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    const char *pos = strstr( record, prefix );

    if ( pos )
    {
        pos += strlen( prefix );
        
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*pos ) ) ++pos;
        
        n = strlen( pos );
    }
    
    char *name = malloc( n + 1 );
    
    if ( name )
    {
        if ( pos )
        {
            strcpy( name, pos );
        }
        else
        {
            *name = '\0';
        }
    }
    
    return name;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *prefix = "at ";
    
    char *name = extract_name( "199 at Amazon", prefix );
    
    puts( name );
    
    free( name );
    
    name = extract_name( "139 at L.L.Bean", prefix );
    
    puts( name );
    
    free( name );
    
    name = extract_name( "379.99 at Best Buy", prefix );
    
    puts( name );
    
    free( name );
    
    name = extract_name( "345 at Nordstrom", prefix );
    
    puts( name );
    
    free( name );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Amazon
L.L.Bean
Best Buy
Nordstrom
```

The function `extract_name`  creates dynamically a character array where it stores the extracted name. If the memory allocation is failed the function returns a null pointer. If the prefix before the name ( in this case it is the string `"at "`) is not found the function returns an empty string.